# Laravel how to disable usage of HTTP Authentication Header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project (without API) that I access trough a Webserver that has HTTP Authentication activated.

The Laravel App try to authenticate me with the submitted HTTP Authentication Headers (this are only used for the Webserver), how I can disable this?

Answer (score 0):

> this are only used for the Webserver

This sense not make any statement does.

If Laravel could influence the configuration of your webserver then your site is very broken. If PHP could override headers added by the webserver then your site is very broken.

You need to change your webserver config to remove the header.